# underscore sortBy function on a backbone collection unable to identify the objects of the collection

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a backbone collection to be sorted. I am using undescore.js function sortBy. Below is my code snippet

`sortedcollection = collectionToSort.sortBy(function(obj){
    return obj.cost;
    })`

But this throws me an error that obj is undefined. This is working only when is write the code as below:

`sortedcollection = collectionToSort.sortBy(function(obj){

    obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));

    return obj.cost;
    });`

My question is why couldn't it identify the     `obj`     object inside the     `sortBy`     function even though it is a JSON object unless i reconvert it into a JSON object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Backbone model is passed to your sortBy function, not the object you initialized the model with.

```
sortedcollection = collectionToSort.sortBy(function(model){
  return model.get('cost')
})
```